# Spring - Template page based on many JSP pages

Tags: java, spring, templates

How can I build an template page, based on many JSP pages with Spring?

I can not use  tag, because I have to set some data to those pages first. I also do not want to implement whole template page ( header, footer ) in every JSP file because only ${content} var will be changing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear for me what your limitations are. Did you take a look to Sitemesh or Apache Tiles?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know, if spring supports this.

Comment: If the question is if Spring has something similar to sitemesh and Tiles I will say no. It is not Spring philosophy to do something that it is already done.

Comment: Ok, to clear things up - is it possible to assign an JSP page ( filled with data ) to other JSP page in Apache Tiles or Sitemesh? I do not want to repeat statement like "<tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />" in every JSP page I will be implementing. I would rather to create one page with var like ${menu}, which will contain rendered menu.jsp page. If my logic is wrong, please correct me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can do it in both. If what you want to do is simple (no many jsp fragments, I recommend sitemesh. In sitemesh, for example, you have a base page, let's say a page composed by header, body, menu and footer where instead body you have a tag (saying body goes here). So you just care about bodies and forget the rest. Sitemesh will manage automatically to add the body (whatever) to your base template.

Answer (score 0):

Use a jsp fragment within your jsp:

```
<%@include file="header.jspf" %>
```